# How could I rename the first 5 files in a folder with a different extension while keeping the old ones the same?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cp

I have about 20 files in a folder. I want to rename the extension of the first 5 from .txt to .html. I want to keep the first 5 files with the .txt extension though. Here is what I have so far. It is a bash script

```
cp 'ls | head -5 "files would go here I think"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
files=(*.txt)
for ((i=0; i<5; i++)); do
    cp -v "${files[i]}" "${files[i]%.txt}.html"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pipe these commands to get what you need.

```
ls *.txt | head -5 | sed -e 's/.txt$//' | xargs -n1 -I% cp %.txt %.html
```